# Convert Tabs-as-spaces width

Tags: eclipse, indentation

I have many source code files which are idented with 8 space characters, I want to convert these to 4 character indents. What is the best way of doing this? A technique using eclipse would be preferable.

Comment: Stop using spaces for indentation. If you used tabs, then you could configure your editor to display them however you want (8 spaces, 4, 256, whatever).

Comment: I hear arguments either way. I used spaces because it's recommended in the Python PEP style guide I'm following. I think it's more of a discussion for another topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the project(s), then press Ctrl+H to open the Search dialog (or click the **Search** > **File** menu).

- Make sure the **File Search** tab is selected at the top.
- Enter 8 spaces into the **Containing text:** field
- Select your **File name pattern** (probably `*.java` or just `*`)
- Select the scope (probably **Selected Resources**)
- Press the **Replace...* button.

As I said in the comments above, however, using spaces for indentation is a fool's game; tabs are the proper abstraction for indentation so that you don't have this problem.

Comment: Also, check the [following link](http://rakesh.sankar-b.com/2011/08/22/convert-tabs-to-spaces-in-eclipse-and-file-in-linux/) that I had wrote which contains the steps to convert tabs to spaces from Eclipse as well as in Linux.